# What is the default capacity of collection framework classes?

Tags: java

I know that the default capacity of `Vector` class in java is 10 and similarly `ArrayList` also have it's default capacity 10. But what is the default capacity of the following classes:

1. Vector
2. ArrayList
3. LinkedList
4. HashMap
5. LinkedHashMap
6. ConcurrentHashMap
7. HashSet
8. LinkedHashSet
9. TreeSet

Or is there any other way to get the default capacity of all collection framework classes in java?

Comment: Not size, `capacity`. Size is 0 for newly created empty collection. For all mentioned classes you can check source code

Comment: Flagged for being too broad. This could be answered by research.

Comment: This could vary depending on the JDK specific implementation. You can check OpenJDK sources. In any case, why you want to know? Your app should not depend in any case on what this value is.

Comment: @m0skit0 in some very specific cases the performance of the application can benefit by presetting the initial size of a collection, but to do so properly you also need to know and understand the algorithm used by each collection class specifically to determine how and when to grow the underlying data storage.

Comment: @jwenting However these are internal details of these classes that can change in the future or if you use another JDK, this is why your optimization should never depend of the internal implementation of any class. This is called [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)) in OOP paradigm.

Comment: @m0skit0 which means that you should not even try to worry about this unless you have a very specific requirement, in which case you're going to write the application to be dependent on that specific JVM anyway.

Comment: @jwenting You mean the JDK, not JVM.

Comment: @m0skit0 no, JVM. You can compile something against one and run it on another and it may behave differently because it has a different runtime environment.

Comment: @jwenting You said it: runtime environment. That's the JRE which is part of the JDK. JVM has nothing to do with the implementations of any Java SDK classes.

Comment: no @m0skit0, the runtime libraries are part of the JVM that is used by both the runtime and compiler. They're not specifically part of the JDK alone, or your compiled application wouldn't be able to run.

Comment: @jwenting You're confusing the JVM runtime libraries with JDK code; the mentioned classes implementations (i.e. ArrayList, LinkedList, etc) are part of the JDK which is independent from the JVM. I suggest you check it out.

Comment: @m0skit0  no, I'm not. The CODE for them is part only of the JDK, the compiled versions are part of the JRE which implements the JVM. Try running a 1.8 JVM without rt.jar and see how well it goes...

Comment: @jwenting Again, you're talking about the JVM runtime, not the classes mentioned in this question.

Comment: @m0skit0 the entire collections api IS part of that, is in the old rt.jar.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no one correct answer here as it will depend on the Java version. For example [RFR JDK-7143928 : (coll) Optimize for Empty ArrayList and HashMap](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2013-April/015585.html) made `ArrayList` and `HashMap` empty by default in Java 8.

You would have to check the default constructor for each of the mentioned classes in your JDK. In theory this could also vary between JDK build (e.g. Oracle, IBM, Azul...) as default `ArrayList` capacity is not part of Java Language Specification.

Comment: So It might be different in java 1.x version ?

Comment: @SudhirOjha absolutely! this is an implementation detail that is subject to change

Comment: @Karol Dowbecki Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6):

```
 1. Vector = 10
 2. ArrayList = 10
 3. LinkedList - does not have a capacity
 4. HashMap = 16 (but with the default load factor of 0.75, only 12 can be populated before a resize will happen)
 5. LinkedHashMap = 16 (read above)  
 6. ConcurrentHashMap = 16
 7. HashSet = 16 (it's  based on a HashMap)
 8. LinkedHashSet = 16
 9. TreeSet = does not have one
```

Just notice that some of them are lazy and all of them are subject to change from release to release.

Comment: What about size of the stack? @Eugene

Answer (score 3):

```
ArrayList = 10

LinkedList = no intial capacity

HashMap,LinkedHashMap,ConcurrentHashMap,HashSet,LinkedHashSet = 16

TreeSet = empty
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at your JDK folder, you will see a file called `src.zip`, containing the sources of the API.

Looking at the source code of `ArrayList`, for example, it seems the default capacity is 10.

Comment: Best answer to question

Comment: @NickProzee in such a case, at least 30% of the question here on SO should say *read the documentation*, instead of quoting and explaining it

Comment: @NickProzee No, this answers the question for the specific JDK you have installed.